# When I try to remove releases in sonatype Nexus using scheduled tasks. It's deleting artifacts randomly? Any idea?

Tags: nexus

When I try to remove releases in sonatype Nexus using scheduled tasks  I am not able to remove releases according correctly. It's deleting artifacts randomly? Any idea? . I mentioned number to keep as 50 and when I upload some artifacts today manually artifacts were deleted after I ran schedule task. Does anyone know how this really works?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the description for how this task operates here:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/scheduled-tasks.html

The important thing to keep in mind is that it only operates on version numbers which use [semantic versions](http://semver.org/).  For Maven, if semantic versions are not used then versions are compared using simple string comparison, it would be dangerous to allow this task to delete artifacts in this case, since string comparison will not necessarily sort versions correctly. You can also find a pretty good description of this [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html).

If your version numbers are not in standard format then don't use the remove old releases task.